# PHP - RegEx isn't working with 5.2, works in 5.1 and 5.3

Tags: php, regex

Here is my regex:

```
$table_pattern = "/<TABLE.*?>(.*?)<\/TABLE>/is";
```

Like the title says, it works in 5.1 and 5.3, but not 5.2. I'm using it in this `preg_match`:

```
preg_match_all($table_pattern, $page_content, $table_content);
```

`$table_content` is `NULL` on 5.2, but populated on 5.1 and 5.3. Any idea as to why?

Additional details:

```
$car_count = 47; //How many cars are currently online
$page_content = file_get_contents('http://www.site.com/temps/inventory.cfm?ChangeItems='.$car_count);; // What page will be parsed
$page_start = 10277; //Where the parsing should start

$page_content = substr($page_content, $page_start); //Removes all of the text above the table we need
$table_pattern = "/\<TABLE.*?\>(.*?)\<\/TABLE\>/is";
preg_match_all($table_pattern, $page_content, $table_content); //Finds all tables inside of $page_content and fills the $table_content array
$final_content = $table_content[0][0]; //Setting the first table, which is the match we need, to $table
```

$final_content is coming up as NULL. Obviously there is more happening below this in my code but it's irrelevant.

I solved my own problem by - wait for it - NOT using RegEx! But really, I initially thought this would be much faster than dealing with the PHP Simple HTML Parser, but it wasn't. But I am still curious as to why this will not work in certain versions.

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Comment: Maybe 5.2 was smart enough to avoid regexing xml. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @tbowman - Can you post the HTML snippet that fails in 5.2 but works on all other versions?

Comment: Do you have full error reporting on? `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`
http://codepad.org/jvr99JBF

Comment: It's an entire web page so I am not going to post it all. I'll turn on error reporting and see what I get out of it. (Edit: no dice)

Comment: Perhaps the [configuration directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php) are different across the versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to parse XML in PHP with recursive regex, but please use an [XML library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead of regex. It's much cleaner and easier...

(Your code fails if you have nested "tables" in your XML...)

The PCRE is developed by another team than the php, and the older versions have bugs. Maybe there is a bug in the PCRE passed to the php 5.2 which is fixed by the later versions.

Another explanation could be, that you have unicode xml, and you didn't use the "u" flag.

By me it works on php 5.2.17. Which version do you have?

Comment: I have since moved on to use the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to accomplish what I needed. I can't recall what exact version it was, I'll have to check again.